# Angular cannot resolve promise

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-promise, angular-services

I have created a service to communicate with a server via $http.post.

```
app.factory("dataService", [
    "$http", "$q", "$timeout", function ($http, $q) {

        function post(url, data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(url, data)
            .success(function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            post: post
        };
```

In the controller I am doing:

```
dataService.get(someUrl,someData).
  then(function (data) {
     $scope.result = data;
 });
```

Everything works fine, but if I call this generic "dataService" in some other service, for an example:

```
 app.factory("userService", ["$http", "$q","dataService", function ($http, $q,dataService) {

        function postUser(user) {
            dataService.post(usersUrl, user);
        }

        return {
            postUser: postUser
        };
    }
```

and call this "userService" in controller 
`userService.postUser($scope.user).then(){}`, I am getting the following error:
[image]

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Just needed to assign resolved promise to variable and then return that variable.

```
   function postUser(user) {
            var result = dataService.post(usersUrl,user);
            return result;
        };
```

Comment: Or you can just do `return dataService.post(usersUrl, user)`, your original code misses the return statement, so your function "returns" undefined on which you try to call `then`.

Comment: Yeah, this is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
app.factory("dataService", [
              "$http", "$timeout", function ($http) {

                function post(url, data) {
                  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    $http.post(url, data)
                      .success(function (result) {
                        resolve(result)
                      })
                      .error(function (error) {
                        resolve(error)
                      });
                  });
                }
                return {
                  post: post
                };
```

And

```
app.factory("userService", ["$http", "$q","dataService", function ($http, $q,dataService) {

              function postUser(user) {
                return dataService.post(usersUrl, user);
              }

              // OR

              function postUser(user,callback) {
                dataService.post(usersUrl, user).then(function(data){callback(data);});
              }

              return {
                postUser: postUser
              };
            }
```

Hope it helps ;)

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6261968)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$q` here.There are a few angular services that return a `$promise`, for example `$http,$timeout,$interval`. Therefore you should not use `$q` here because a promise is already returned by the `$http` service.
Your service should look like this:

```
.factory('myService', function($http) {
       return {
        postMyData : function(){
        return $http.post(data);
 }
```

At this point you already have a promise returned by the `$http` angular service. Now you can just resolve it as you want ( controller ).
For example:

```
var myPromise = myService.postMyData(data).
        myPromise.then(function(){//success
                  },function(){//error
                  },function(){//inform that action is in progress
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `userService.postUser($scope.user).then(){}` the function in `userService` should return the promise:

```
 function postUser(user) {
   return dataService.post(usersUrl, user);
 }
```